# como sacar dos ventanas de confirmacion con swall antes de que se ejecute la accion?

Tags: javascript, php, json

```
    swal({title: "Información",text: "¿Desea rechazar la solicitud de usuario ? "info",buttons: {cancel: true,confirm: true,cancel: {text: "Cancelar",visible: true}},})
```

este cod me mostra una ventana de confirmacion de si deseo o no rechazar la solicitud ... pero deseo que antes de que se ejecute ese swal aparesca otro preguntandome el motivo ... al insertar el motivo se ejecuta el swal ya mostrado aqui... podrian ayudarme porfa ?

Comment: Que versión de swal2 utilizas?

Comment: disculpa no sabria decirte como puedo verificarlo ?

Comment: Perdón, debería ser... Que versión de swal utilizas? La 2 o la 1.

Comment: la 2 version ....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar este ejemplo de la [documentación de SweetAlert2](https://sweetalert2.github.io/#examples):

```js
Swal.fire({
  title: 'Are you sure?',
  text: "You won't be able to revert this!",
  icon: 'warning',
  showCancelButton: true,
  confirmButtonColor: '#3085d6',
  cancelButtonColor: '#d33',
  confirmButtonText: 'Yes, delete it!'
}).then((result) => {
  if (result.isConfirmed) {
    Swal.fire(
      'Deleted!',
      'Your file has been deleted.',
      'success'
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
```

Comment: y a ese alert se le puede poner una caja de texto q guarde en la bd antes de hacer la accion ?

Comment: Si claro, pero tienes que hacer la lógica para eso.